# Naming convention for JSF pages

Tags: java, jsf

In Java, there's a naming convention for classes, interfaces, packages, methods, variables and constants. I'm just wondering if there is a naming convention for JSF XHTML pages.

Here are a few variants that came up to my mind:

- `MyPage.xhtml`
- `myPage.xhtml`
- `my-page.xhtml`
- `mypage.xhtml`

Comment: For page addresses, I usually recommend simple cases (i.e., the last one you have there) because this is something your users may need to hand-type into the browser. It's impractical to expect them to remember the nuances of the specific case you programmed it in. Remember, this is not code, so camel case here is not doing your end users any favours

Comment: @kolossus, but don't you think it's confusing and difficult for reading?

Comment: Not if you separate phrase-page names with a hyphen. my-page.xhtml is just fine. As an end user, I won't remember (or even know) what special case is applicable to a page. Just look above you on this very page and observe the naming convention. IMO, if you anticipate or ever expect your users to type anything into the address bar, it's too much work to expect them to consider or remember case. That's just my opinion (hence why I'm not posting an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camel-case starting with a lowercase letter is good, I use hyphens to distinguish modules/ subpages/ subelements.

For example:

- productList.xhtml
- productEdit.xhtml
- productEdit-buttons.xhtml
- productReport.xhtml
- customerAddress.xhtml
- customerAddress-map.xhtml

Not a formal convention, but it works well. Being able to modularize or identify fragments or sub-functions is useful.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to think of xhtml pages as something different from plain html pages. In the end, if a user has to type it out, then it would help to have a simple page name (just like we would name any html page).

To give you an example, even a company like Apple who are so specific about using the correct case for their products, still maintain a URL such as [http://www.apple.com/iphone](http://www.apple.com/iphone/)! (iPhone is written as iphone)

To summarize I would say, don't use capital letters in URL, and try not to use special characters either.